# MVC 4 theme switching with Ajax.ActionLinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, asp.net-mvc-partialview

The full text of this question is available with a screenshot [here](http://pdvstheweb.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/mvc-4-theme-switching-with.html)

Thanks for any help - original post follows:

So I downloaded the MvcMusicStore and fired up the completed project.  I read all the articles talking about extending the view engine and using jquery plugins but I wanted to believe it could be simpler than that to just change the CSS file path when a link gets clicked.  Mainly because I didn't want to copy code verbatim that I didn't fully understand.  I'm very new to MVC.

So this is what I did:

To HomeController.cs I added:

```
    public ActionResult Theme(string themeName)
    {
        ViewBag.Theme = ThemeModel.GetSetThemeCookie(themeName);
        return View();
    }
```

to Models I added this class:

```
public class ThemeModel
{
    public static string GetSetThemeCookie(string theme)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("userTheme");
        string rv = "Blue";
        if (theme != null)
            rv = theme;
        else
        {
            if (cookie != null)
                rv = cookie["themeName"];
            else
                rv = "Blue";
        }

        cookie = new HttpCookie("userTheme");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("userTheme");
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(100);
        cookie["themeName"] = rv;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        return rv;

    }
}
```

I then created 2 copies of Site.css, changing only the background color and font-family and a view to generate my link tag.

```
<link href="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/{0}.css", ViewBag.Theme))" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Finally, I made these changes to my _Layout.cshtml.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @if (ViewBag.Theme == null) {Html.RenderAction("Theme", "Home");}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1><a href="/">ASP.NET MVC MUSIC STORE</a></h1>
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li class="first"><a href="@Url.Content("~")" id="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Store/")">Store</a></li>
        <li>@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");}</li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/StoreManager/")">Admin</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

@{Html.RenderAction("GenreMenu", "Store");}

<div id="main">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Themes: @Ajax.ActionLink("Coral", "Theme", "Home", new { themeName = "Coral" }, null, new { @style = "color : coral"} )
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Blue", "Theme", "Home", new { themeName = "Blue" }, null, new { @style = "color : blue;"})

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the app I get the general layout rendered twice.  Once with only the genre menu rendered on the left and nothing in the body. And then again with the top 5 albums.  I can't post the image as I don't have enough rep.

When I click my Coral and Blue links, my theme changes and I get just the one set without the top 5 albums.

So after some more reading on here I tried this:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Theme", "Home");}
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public ActionResult Theme(string themeName)
    {
        ViewBag.Theme = ThemeModel.GetSetThemeCookie(themeName);
        return PartialView();
    }
```

But even though this stops the duplicate rendering, when I click the theme link, the colour changes but I get absolutely nothing else on the page.

Well and truly flummoxed now and could really use some help.

Cheers,
.pd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - here's how I did it in the end.

Create a javascript file.  Mine's called master.js:

```
function ajaxSuccSetTheme(theme) {
    $('#linkTheme').attr('href', '/Content/' + theme + '.css');
}
```

Modify the _Layout.cshtml:

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.Theme == null) {
        ViewBag.Theme = MvcMusicStore.Models.ThemeModel.GetSetThemeCookie();
    }
}
<link id="linkTheme" href="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/{0}.css", ViewBag.Theme))" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/master.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Notes on this:

- The first time the page loads Theme will not have been written to the ViewBag
- Give the `<link>` tag the same ID as the jQuery selector in your js file above
- Update unobtrusive ajax jQuery file to the same version as your jQuery lib.  Your Ajax.ActionLink won't work without it.

Then my theme switching links in _Layout.cshtml look like this:

```
<div id="footer">
    Themes :
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Coral", "Theme", "Home", new { themeName = "Coral" }, 
            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = string.Format("ajaxSuccSetTheme('{0}');", "Coral")}, 
            new { @style = "color : coral;" }) | 
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Blue", "Theme", "Home", new { themeName = "Blue" }, 
            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = string.Format("ajaxSuccSetTheme('{0}');", "Blue")}, 
            new { @style = "color : blue;" })
</div>
```

Notes on that:

- themeName = "whatever" is the argument to your Theme Controller method. this gets passed to the cookie method in the ThemeModel
- method = POST so IE doesn't cache it and I've read a couple other questions that got solved by not doing a GET
- you have to kludge your own args to the OnSuccess js callback

Next the HomeController.cs change:

```
    public ActionResult Theme(string themeName)
    {
        ViewBag.Theme = ThemeModel.GetSetThemeCookie(themeName);
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Honestly, it doesn't matter if you just return null without checking for `IsAjaxRequest()` cuz all we need from this is to set the cookie so it remembers when you next login.

Which just leaves the cookie setting method in the ThemeModel:

```
public class ThemeModel
{
    public static string GetSetThemeCookie(string theme = null)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("userTheme");
        string rv = "Blue";
        if (theme != null)
            rv = theme;
        else
        {
            if (cookie != null)
                rv = cookie["themeName"];
            else
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie("userTheme");
                rv = "Blue";
            }
        }

        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(100);
        cookie["themeName"] = rv;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        return rv;

    }
}
```

Hope I helped somebody.  If you'd rather do it all in jQuery here's [Tim Vanfosson's Theme Manager jQuery Plugin](http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/jquery-theme-manager-plugin.html)

Cheers,

.pd.